# How to find basename of path via pipe

Tags: bash, shell, find, basename

This doesn't work:

```
find "$all_locks" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | basename
```

apparently basename cannot read from stdin - in any case basename requires at least one argument.

Comment: Are you simply looking to strip off the final directory name, or are you looking to find the parents of things that might be symbolic links from `$all_locks`?

Comment: I am just trying to get the basename of each path resulting from find

Comment: So if `/path/to/this` is a symlink to `/some/other/place`, should your result be `/path/to` or `/some/other`?

Answer (score 30):

To apply a command to every result of a piped operation, [xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) is your friend. As it says on the man page I linked...

> xargs reads items from the standard input, delimited by blanks (which
>   can be protected with double or single quotes or a backslash) or
>   newlines, and executes the command (default is /bin/echo) one or more
>   times with any initial-arguments followed by items read from standard
>   input.

In this case that means it will take each result from your `find` command and run `basename <find result>`ad nauseum, until find has completed its search. I believe what you want is going to look a lot like this:

`find "$all_locks" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | xargs basename`

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is `basename` doesn't accept the `stdin` and hence unnamed pipes may not be useful. I would like to modify your command a little bit. Let me know if it serves the purpose.

```
find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec basename {}  \;
```

Note: Not enough reputation to comment, hence posting it here.

Comment: on ubuntu bash 4, I get `find: missing argument to '-exec'`...weird

Comment: @MrCholo, I hope you didn't miss a space between `{}` and \ ? Because, I can recreate your problem by erasing that space.

Answer (score 6):

Since `mindepth` and `maxdepth` are GNU extensions, using another one such as `printf` will not make it less portable.

```
find "$all_locks" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%f\n'
```